# How to calculate difference between BMI and Average in this spreadsheet

Tags: libreoffice

I have this libreoffice calc spreadsheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZVBb.jpg and i need help to calculate BMI DIFF. So i need to substract Average from BMI if BMI is higher than average and in need to substract BMI from average if average is higher. How to do that? I've been trying with if function but every time it substracts average from bmi even if average is higher. How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried with the `abs` function?

Comment: Yea but it doesnt work. I need to get -6 in F4 for example.

Comment: If you need -6.195 in cell F4, then don't use IF() - just write in F2 =`E2-$B$11` and stretch the formula down

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- Please use the provided image tool. -- Please show us the formula you use, and the expected output. [Edit] your question, don't add new information in a comment.